# How can I include js file in Angularjs2 component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I try to include *.js in [ *.component.html ] file

like this :

```
<script src="modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it doesn't load.

Only success I got , when I try to load *.js is in src/index.html.

I am a newbie at Angular2 ,I don't know how to load js flie in Angular 2 project .

any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

`<script>` tags in templates are not added to the DOM, they are just stripped from the template. You need to use other means to add the script. For example `require()`

Comment: Thanks your answer,I try to write typescript code in my project,don't use native js file.

Comment: Not sure what your comment means. Do you need a different answer?

Comment: No,I think use Typescript in Angularjs 2 project is best way,Reduce use Javascript